# *ngIf and else statement not working

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to work with *ngIf and else statements and they are not working properly in Angular.
I have an object that contains details about a missions, and I have 3 status situation linked to 3 types of button: pending, finished and not touched yet. It means, the first 2 situations, pending and finished, the user interacted with them and they are in the database, but in the 3rd case, user haven't interacted yet with them and they are not in the database.
So: I have a button when the status == finished, 1 for the status == pending, but the 3rd is giving me pain, due to the fact that I don't have it in the database, so I can't check it after some criteria. So I decided to go with ngIf and else statement, but they are not working so good, meaning that the 3rd button is showed all the time, even if the if statement is true, it goes on the else.

Can anyone help me solve this out?

Thanks in advance!

```
<h3 class="card-title">Misiuni</h3>
<div *ngFor="let proj of projects" id="{{proj}}">
    <h4>Proiect: {{proj}}</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let item of missions; let indexRow = index">
        <div class="ribbon-wrapper card" *ngIf="item.project==proj">
            <div >
            <div class="ribbon ribbon-default" ><a href="mission-details/{{ item.id }}">{{ item.title }}</a></div>
                <p class="ribbon-content">{{ item.description }} </p>
                    <br><h4 class="card-title">Reward:</h4>
                    <img src="{{item.reward}}" width="250px" height="150px">
                    <br><h4 class="card-title">Experiență: {{item.exp}}</h4>
                    <div *ngIf="missionsStatus.length  !== 0">
                        <div *ngFor="let itm of missionsStatus">
                            <input disabled="true" *ngIf="itm?.status == 'finished' && itm?.status != 'pending' && item.id == itm?.id_mission; else new" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-mission-finalize" value="Misiune finalizata" align="center">
                            <input disabled="true" *ngIf="itm?.status == 'pending' && itm?.status != 'finished' && item.id == itm?.id_mission; else new" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-mission-pending" value="Misiune in curs" align="center">
                            <ng-template #new>
                                    <input (click)="missionAccept(item?.id)" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Accepta misiunea1" align="center">
                            </ng-template>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="missionsStatus.length  == 0">
                        <input  type="submit" (click)="missionAccept(item?.id)" class="btn btn-danger" value="Accepta misiunea" align="center">
                    </div>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

Comment: why would the length of `missionStatus` be 0?  should you just be checking `*ngIf="!missionsStatus"` to check if it is falsey or `*ngIf="missionsStatus"` if it is truthy?

Comment: Because there are no current missions pending, so the object would be empty. It works well that part

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean, now.  I didn't see an `ngIf` on the third button, so I think I was confused as to what you tried.  Can you use `*ngIf="itm?.status !== 'finished' && itm?.status !== 'pending' && item.id === itm?.id_mission"` for the status checks on the third button?

Comment: It is not showing the button at all under this condition, because the item.id === itm?.id_mission can't be true due to the fact that in itm, the id_mission in this condition does not exist.

Comment: Kindly show your missions and missionsStatus sample data what you are got data. It is easy to solve your problem